# Diffraction across an absorbing wall

Tags: differential-equations, physics, wave-equation

I need help finding the procedure for the solution of the following differential equation.

This is equation is: Find $u:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ such that for $C>0$

$ \begin{cases} u_{xx}+  u_{yy}+k^2 u=0\;\; \mbox{if} \;\;y\neq 0\\
u_{xx}+  u_{yy}+k^2 u=0\;\; \mbox{if} \;\;y=0\;\;\mbox{and}\;\; x<-1
\;\;\mbox{or}\;\;x>1\\
Cu(x,0)=-e^{ixk\cos\theta}\;\;\mbox{if}\;\;-1\le x\le 1\\
|u|\to 0\;\;\mbox{as}\;\;x^2+y^2\to\infty
\end{cases}$

Comment: Yes, this is equivalent to diffraction from metallic screen with conductivity $\sigma\to \infty$. This is a classic problem.

Comment: can you please give me more details or a reference as to where I can find the details?

I realised that the problem must be solved somewhere, I simply haven't been able to find where.

Comment: Born, Wolf, Principles of Optics

Comment: I have looked in this book and could not find this particular problem.